# Appcelerator CLI - can't login

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-cli

I've reinstalled my Windows machine and I have installed the Appc CLI from npm (did not install Appcelerator Studio this time).
When I do `appc setup` I get to the login phase, and after entering my credentials it's stuck. Even tried closing the console window and starting a new one and doing `appc login` - again entering my credentials and it's stuck....
What am I missing?

If I run the following `appc login -l trace` then after putting my username and password I see that it does not go beyond `Get the registry...`

Comment: Hello, You need to have node version 8.x.x, Node 10.x.x is having an issue in the Windows platform with Appcelerator, And 11.x.x is not supported yet. 10.x.x is supported with Linux and Mac platform. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced the same problem with **node v10.15.0** & googled about the problem. I found lots of posts suggesting me to **clean the installation of node & delete all the related directories** from **Program Files** or **User Profile** or **Appdata**. I did the same & reinstalled node v10.15.0 and then installed appcelerator cli. But i couldn't able to get it working.

After that, i discussed about it with one of my colleague & he suggested to install some earlier version of node ( 8.11.4 instead of 10.15.0 ). I tried it after cleaning previous installations & This time i ended up with success.

So try with earlier versions of node.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the below commands in Administrative command prompt.

```sh
rm -rf ~/.appcelerator

rm -rf ~/.titanium

npm uninstall -g titanium

npm uninstall -g appcelerator

npm install -g appcelerator

appc config set proxyServer null

appc use latest

appc setup
```